# AS3 Vector.sort() does not take sorting options?

Tags: actionscript-3, sorting, flash

In AS3, `Array.sort()` took some nice sorting options like:

- **Array.DESCENDING** - sorts the array big to small
- **Array.RETURNINDEXEDARRAY** - returns an array of indices so you can track which item got sorted where

But sadly `Vector<T>.sort()` does not support these features, and simply takes a `compareFunction:Function` argument so you can write your own sorting logic.

Is there any other way to quickly get a sorted indexed-array of a vector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RETURNINDEXEDARRAY` does not work in Flash Player 10+. It just returns the same original `Vector<Number>`.

Unlike an Array, `RETURNINDEXEDARRAY` option is ignored for the `Vector.sort()` method. The returned Vector object is always the reference of the original object.

Answer (score 8):

Check out the documentation : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html#sort()

It is still possible to use those options but you have to pass them in as the first parameter instead of the compare function.

```
 myVector.sort(Array.DESCENDING|Array.RETURNINDEXEDARRAY);
```

Comment: Array.RETURNINDEXEDARRAY does not work for me. It just returns the same original Vector<Number>

Comment: Yeah I was reading the comments on the documentation page and found this :
"Unlike an Array class, Array.RETURNINDEXEDARRAY option seems to be ignored for the Vector.sort() method.  The returned Vector object is always the reference of the original object."

Comment: Also beware that the second argument in the slice method is not optional, despite the docs.